# AWS - SQS FIFO - message can't be deleted - the receipt handle has expired

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sqs-fifo

### [image]**Polling Duration - 10sec**

### **Visibility Timeout - 1min.**

**1-** deleting message within polling duration -> **Success**

**2-** deleting message after polling duration is over but within visibility timeout period -> **Fail**

when I try to delete a message within the **visibility timeout** period but after **polling duration** is over.

Message can't be deleted
->  Reason: The receipt handle has expired.

### Shouldn't a consumer be allowed to delete a message if **visibility timeout** is not over or does it also depend on **polling duration**?

Comment: What exactly did you do? Can you provide any code or exact steps to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I am using AWS UI for both sending and receiving messages.
I have added some SS for better understanding.